# Why was my answer (on m4a sound) deleted?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221191/is-there-a-good-java-sound-library-i-can-use-to-play-mpeg-4-audio-m4a-files

I posted with an (admittedly rather short) response recommending JAAD, and while it was short I didn't see the need to make it any longer (after all, JAAD is a library that plays M4A files, why flesh it out for no reason?)

So why was it deleted? The only reason I can think of is that it was phrased as a question, but that still seems rather heavy handed to me considering it was a useful reply (and because it was deleted an essentially duplicate question popped up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720664/play-m4a-files-in-java/16720795#16720795).)

Comment: It reads like a link-only comment to me, I'd have flagged it as 'not an answer'. Presumably your answer was flagged as such, a moderator deleted it and that invariably means they are responding to one or more flags on the post.

Comment: I posted on your newest answer. I think that you answer the users question sufficiently but part of that is though comments. I suggested that you add that information to your answer. At that point I would consider it a very good answer.

Comment: The question itself should be closed and eventually deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am the mod who deleted that post. It was flagged for moderator attention, and I saw that it was a "link-only" answer, and so deleted it. What I did *not* see at the time was the question was asking for a library recommendation, so the problem really was the whole question - not simply your answer.

I have closed the question now, and am looking at the other one you linked to here.

Comment: This used to be handled with the "convert to comment" option.  New policy?

Comment: I've gone ahead and converted. We don't always do that, though. In this case, the question is likely to be deleted at some point. @UphillLuge

Answer (score 0):

The post functioned as a conversation starter rather than an ender. Your answer would be better posted as a comment for two reasons:

1. It was posted in question form.
2. If the OP answered "yes" to your question, it would not function as an answer even if phrased as a statement.

If you had said "JAAD is the way to go because X, Y, and Z" it would have been a real answer.